# Java scanner will not read empty line at end of file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a file parser that reads a data file

```
BREAK ;
     FI
 REPEAT
  PRINT "bye all"
.
//empty line
```

and parses chars, spaces, (, ; etc. and storing each item in a Arraylist. I can read empty lines at the head and body but not the end.

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(path));
int count = 0;
while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
    count++;
    line.clear();
    System.out.println("hasNext");
    //line holds entire line since scanner skips spaces
    String a = fileInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("a is String" + a);
    int i = 0;
    String str = ""; // used to store single word and spaces
    boolean stop = false;
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        line.add("EoLn");
        System.out.println("line " + count + " EOL");
    }
}
```

Full Source https://gist.github.com/dcf7a215f3582bae962a.git[1]

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: It will parse everything but the empty string at the end of the file.

Comment: And then just stops? `hasNextLine()` returns false? And what is `boolean stop` for?

Comment: Does the file end in a newline?

Comment: NB Your source link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default `Scanner` uses whitespace as a delimiter. You could do

```
fileInput.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: I used scanner to read in a line and save to a string then scanner.charAt() for each character.

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying there...please clarify to us

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing in the line to parse on whitespace delimiters, maybe `Scanner` considers the line insignificant. Your code looks OK. As you're only reading lines with it, I would switch to `BufferedReader.readLine().`